CPU use increases over time with simple swiftui animation
I created a simple animation of a circle that changes sizes. The circle pulses like a heartbeat in the center of the screen. My expectation is for the CPU use to be very low, but that is not the case. In addition, even if the CPU use isn't as low as I would expect, I do not expect the CPU use to increase over time because nothing else is happening in the app. Here is the code:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {

  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      ZStack {
        SplashNucleusView(minSize: 50, maxSize: 100)
      }
    }
  }

}

struct SplashNucleusView: View {
  let minSize: Double
  let maxSize: Double

  @State private var nucleusColor: Color = .primary
  @State private var nucleusRadius: Double = 10
  @State private var nucleusOpacity: Double = 1.0

  private var nucleusAnimation: Animation {
    .easeInOut(duration: 0.25)
    .repeatForever(autoreverses: true)
  }

  let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.5, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()

  var body: some View {
    Circle()
      .fill(nucleusColor)
      .frame(width: nucleusRadius)
      .opacity(nucleusOpacity)
      .onReceive(timer) { _ in
        withAnimation(nucleusAnimation) {
          nucleusRadius = Double.random(in: minSize...maxSize)
        }
      }
  }

}

This is how the animation looks:

The animation is snappy until the CPU use reaches 95%, at which point there is visible stuttering. Here is how the CPU looks when the animation duration value is 0.5 seconds and the timer publishing interval is 3 seconds:

Changing the animation duration value to 0.25 seconds and the timer publishing interval to 0.5 seconds changes the CPU use as follows:

The final animation has many other moving parts, which make the issue much worse. The issue is evident with only the circle view. I spent hours working with the debugger, reading about animations, and testing new approaches, but the result is always the same.
Why is this happening?
EDIT:
Based on lorem ipsum's answer, I implemented three more solutions. Unfortunately, the results are the same even after removing the let timer = ... line:
    // Solution 2
    TimelineView(.periodic(from: .now, by: 3)) { context in
      Circle()
        .fill(nucleusColor)
        .frame(width: nucleusRadius)
        .opacity(nucleusOpacity)
        .onChange(of: context.date) {
          withAnimation(nucleusAnimation) {
            nucleusRadius = Double.random(in: minSize...maxSize)
          }
        }
    }

    // Solution 3
    Circle()
      .fill(nucleusColor)
      .frame(width: nucleusRadius)
      .opacity(nucleusOpacity)
      .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { output in
        withAnimation(nucleusAnimation) {
          nucleusRadius = Double.random(in: minSize...maxSize)
        }
      }

    // Solution 4
    Circle()
      .fill(nucleusColor)
      .frame(width: nucleusRadius)
      .opacity(nucleusOpacity)
      .task {
        repeat {
          try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.25))
          withAnimation(nucleusAnimation) {
            nucleusRadius = Double.random(in: minSize...maxSize)
          }
        } while true
      }


let timer = Timer... is actually not a good practice with SwiftUI and you could end up with memory leaks since SwiftUI can recreate the View at any time and create multiple timers.
The "best" way to handle animations and such is with TimelineView
TimelineView(.periodic(from: startDate, by: 1)) { context in
     AnalogTimerView(date: context.date)
}

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/timelineview
But if you have to use Timer you should use it with onReceive so it gets destroyed appropriately.
 .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) { output in
    print("Timer called")
}

If you can also move into async/await and start using Task as an alternative.
struct TimerSample: View {
    @State private var isDisabled: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        Button("Hello World!") {
            
        }.disabled(isDisabled)
            .task(id: isDisabled) {
                guard isDisabled else {return}
                try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(2))
                isDisabled.toggle()
            }
    }
}


Thank you for the help and information. I updated the post with new screenshots of the CPU use after modifying the timer instantiation. I could not figure out how to use the TimelineView, so I am not sure how to check the differences with that implementation.
Unfortunately, the CPU use is just as bad with the improved timer instantiation technique.

I updated the post again to show the output of the TimelineView, which, unfortunately, is still using an increasing amount of CPU time.

@Anthony surprisingly I think the issue is the ZStack, this might be a genuine bug. If you remove it the leak seems to go away. Try using background or overlay instead of a ZStack

I tried this: Text("").overlay(SplashNucleusView(minSize: 10, maxSize: 25, interval: 0.5)), but the results appeared to be the same. The only thing I've been able to do to influence the CPU use is remove the repeatForever property.

After much heartache, I finally figured out the issue. repeatForever behaves in an unexpected (at least to me) way. It appears to cause the animation to queue, which means each time the Timer or TimelineView publishes a new value, a new animation begins. Over time, this causes a linear increase in the number of active animations.
I ended up using this solution:
import SwiftUI

struct SplashNucleusView: View {
  let minSize: Double
  let maxSize: Double
  let interval: Double

  init(
    minSize: Double = 10,
    maxSize: Double = 25,
    interval: Double = 0.5
  ) {
    self.minSize = minSize
    self.maxSize = maxSize
    self.interval = interval
  }

  @State private var color: Color = .primary
  @State private var radius: Double = 10
  @State private var opacity: Double = 1.0

  var body: some View {
    TimelineView(.periodic(from: .now, by: interval)) { context in
      Circle()
        .fill(color)
        .frame(width: radius)
        .opacity(opacity)
        .onChange(of: context.date) {
          withAnimation(.easeIn(duration: interval / 2)) {
            radius = Double.random(in: minSize...maxSize)
          } completion: {
            withAnimation(.easeOut(duration: interval / 2)) {
              radius = Double.random(in: minSize...maxSize)
            }
          }
        }
    }
  }
}

#Preview {
  SplashNucleusView(minSize: 30, maxSize: 50, interval: 0.5)
}



The effect is not quite the same, so I'll need to tweak the animation to get the same pulsing effect. However, the CPU use is steady at a low percentage, which means the underlying issue has been resolved.
In summary, be careful with repeatForever.
